# Beamer box problem

Tags: beamer, amsmath, boxes, multicol

I am working in "Frankurt" theme on my beamer presentation. Sometimes I am faced with overflow problems. For example:

```
\begin{frame}
\begin{definition}
\begin{multicols}{2}
\begin{enumerate}[a)]
\item $\frac{2x+3}{5x+7}$
\item $\frac{2x^3+7}{x^3-x^2+x+7}$
\item $\frac{x+1}{x^2+3}$               
\item $\frac{2\sqrt{x}+x^{-1}}{3x-7}$                   
\item $\frac{2+\sqrt{x}}{2-\sqrt{x}}$               
\item $\frac{\sqrt[3]{x}-\sqrt[5]{x}}{\sqrt[3]{x}+\sqrt[5]{x}}$ 
\item $\frac{x^{-1}+x^{-4}}{x^{-2}-x^{-3}}$
\item $\frac{\sqrt[3]{x}-5x+3}{2x +x^{\frac{2}{3}}-4}$          
\end{enumerate}
\end{multicols}
\end{definition}
\end{frame}
```

Here the part of the last item does not fit into my "definition box".

I have no idea what is the problem. Usually i "solve" these issues by inserting a blank line (or $\phantom{a}$) after \end{multicols}. However I believe that there should be a better way to fix this.

Could you help me?

[image]

Comment: You write your fractions with the *inline mode* `$x$`, so it have to fit in a line.
You should use the $display style* for maths.

Comment: Hi! \displaystyle did not help. I attach a screenshot from the problem...

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `\raggedcolumns` option to prevent the bottom lines of the `multicols` enviroment from being aligned.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Frankfurt}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{amsmath,multicol}

\raggedcolumns

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Frame title}
\begin{definition}
\begin{multicols}{2}
\begin{enumerate}[a)]
\item $\frac{2x+3}{5x+7}$
\item $\frac{2x^3+7}{x^3-x^2+x+7}$
\item $\frac{x+1}{x^2+3}$               
\item $\frac{2\sqrt{x}+x^{-1}}{3x-7}$                   
\item $\frac{2+\sqrt{x}}{2-\sqrt{x}}$               
\item $\frac{\sqrt[3]{x}-\sqrt[5]{x}}{\sqrt[3]{x}+\sqrt[5]{x}}$ 
\item $\frac{x^{-1}+x^{-4}}{x^{-2}-x^{-3}}$
\item $\frac{\sqrt[3]{x}-5x+3}{2x +x^{\frac{2}{3}}-4}$          
\end{enumerate}
\end{multicols}
\end{definition}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Hi! Your advice helped perfectly in the cases when the longer column is the second (I am using only two-column variations...) one. The following code makes the other type of formula list, and is not displayed correctly.

Comment: `\begin{definition}
  \begin{multicols}{2}
   \begin{enumerate}[a)]
    \item $\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{\sin 3x}{4x}=?$
    \item $\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{x}{\sin 2x}=?$    
    \item $\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{x}{\textnormal{tg } 2x}=?$    
    \item $\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{x+x\cos x}{\sin x \cos x}=?$
    \item $\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{x^2-x+\sin x}{2x}=?$    
    \item $\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{\cos x-1}{x^2}=?$    
    \item $\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{\sin 2x}{\sin 3x}=?$    
   \end{enumerate}
  \end{multicols}
 \end{definition}`

Comment: @Alex I think the problem is related to the way by which `multicol` calculates the depth of the last row. The default is `\rlap{\phantom p}` according to the manual. For your large inline math fractions you need to increase this. Unfortunately however, my LaTeX programming skills are not sufficient to solve this issue.